# How can I create a list of online/active users?

Tags: meteor

I'm using the package mizzao:user-status to add online/active statuses to my users. Using this, I'm able to run a query to get all online users.

The problem I'm facing is, keeping a list of users up to date with users that are logged in.

I believe I would need to use `Accounts.onLogin` to update the list, which I think is used on the server side. So, how would I keep a list of users up to date with users that are connected on the client side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like mizzao point on the [README](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status).

**First** Do the Publish.

```
Meteor.publish("userStatus", function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true });
});
```

and the `subscribe`,

```
Meteor.subscribe('userStatus')
```

**Second** do a helper to return the users online.

**Javascript**

```
Template.example.helpers({
  usersOnline:function(){
    return Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true })
  },
  usersOnlineCount:function(){
   //event a count of users online too.
   return Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true }).count();
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="example">
 There are currently {{usersOnlineCount}} users online.
<h1>List of Users online </h1>
  <ul>
   {{#each usersOnline}}
   <li> {{username}}</li>
   {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```